# How to send mime multipart restful request with different content types in java

Tags: java, rest, mime, multipart

I have a bunch of requests of type xml and/or base64 encoded image that I want to send it to client's server, they have their REST API. There is also a need to combine multiple requests into one to efficiently utilize the bandwidth. So I was thinking of using mime-multipart request. What library I can use in java to accomplish this. I know how to send a regular httpRequest in java but I dont know how to send a multipart mime request? i.e. how will I specify different content type for each of the body? Would appreciate any pointers.

I want to send something like this

```
Content-type: multipart/form-data;boundary=main_boundary

--main_boundary
Content-type: text/xml
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<content>
Some content goes here
</content>

--main_boundary
Content-type: multipart/mixed;boundary=sub_boundary

--main_boundary
Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8

 {base64 encoded string that represents image}

--main_boundary--
```

Feel free to correct me if I am wrong in my understanding. This is the first time I am using mime.

Answer (score 0):

The Apache HttpClient library can help you construct multipart requests for file uploads.

Have a look [here](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/methods/multipartpost.html). And here is a [sample application](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpcomponents/oac.hc3x/trunk/src/examples/MultipartFileUploadApp.java?view=markup).